# Cannot Connect Android Studio To My Phone Or Bluestacks

Tags: android-studio

I have been trying to connect Android Studio to a device, but have not been successful. No matter which device I use, none of them are recognizable by Android Studio. I have tried following the official tutorial of [running your app](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device?page=2&tab=Votes) Stackoverflow post as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721778/adb-no-devices-found) one. I then tried to connect to Bluestacks [using this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317727/how-do-you-adb-to-bluestacks-4). None of the above links work for me. ADB does recognize the devices I have been using (Bluestacks and my Huawei Y7 Pro). Any idea of how I can get Android Studio to recognize a device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue:

- I went back and retraced my steps. I noticed this error on the
  console: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsFRw.png)
- I then researched this error and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607089/new-gradle-sync-is-not-supported-due-to-containing-kotlin-modules-using-an-unsup) solution:

  - Click on 'File' on the top left corner of Android Studio editor.
  - Select 'Settings'.
  - Select 'Kotlin Compiler' from the left.
  - Make sure 'Language version' and 'API version' is set to 'Latest stable (1.3)'
  - Make sure 'Target JVM version' is set to '1.8' (this was the problem in my case).
  - Wait for a while.
  - And if you haven't yet configured developer mode on your device then follow [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app) tutorial.